# How do you get x amounts of y in one string and put it in another string in python?

Tags: python, string, letters

If the string is "43 Lobsters and 3 Crabs"
I want to get only the s's from this string. There are three s's so in my new string I must have just "sss".

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: This is probably not the way but I tried slicing each s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont you use the count function?

```
thestr = "43 Lobsters and 3 Crabs"
y = 's'
x = thestr.count(y)
```

so now you know how many times it appears in the string
use that variable to construct a string

```
finstr = y * x
```

Comment: Don't use built-ins as variable names. `str` is a function in Python.

Comment: Close, but `string` is also a module in the standard library :)

Comment: To specifically construct the string, something like `'s'*string.count('s')` would work.

Comment: @MattDMo there we go haha

Comment: Err, this answer doesn't actually full answer the question yet. You still need to incorporate JesseMu's suggestion in.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
>>> strng = '43 Lobsters and 3 Crabs'
>>> ''.join([letter for letter in strng if letter == 's'])
'sss'
```

Here we use a simple list comprehension to iterate through the string, and check if each letter matches the letter `s`. This creates a list, and to make it into a string you just use the `join` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try iterating over the characters of the string and if the character equals s, you take it to build a string. At the end the string would be "sss" if there were 3 's' in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried anything so far?

Try a **for loop**:

One line (called "List Comprehension"):

```
input_string = "43 Lobsters and 3 Crabs" # Input line
answer = "".join(["s" for letter in input_string if letter == "s"]) 
# List comprehension
# "".join is to combine the list into a string

print (answer) # Output
# It is in parenthesis because I do not know your Python version

# Returns sss
```

Usual for loop:

```
input_string = "43 Lobsters and 3 Crabs" # Input line
answer = "" # Answer to which we will add "s"s as needed
for letter in input_string: # For loop
    if letter == "s":
        answer += "s" # Adding "s" to final if it is an "s"

print (answer) # Output

# Returns sss
```

---

If you want it to be **case insensitive**, add `.lower()` to the input:

```
input_string = "43 Lobsters and 3 Crabs" # Input line
answer = "".join(["s" for letter in input_string.lower() if letter == "s"]) 

print (answer) # Output

# Returns sss regardless if it is capitalized or not
```

Or:

```
input_string = "43 Lobsters and 3 Crabs".lower() # Input line
answer = "".join(["s" for letter in input_string if letter == "s"]) 

print (answer) # Output

# Returns sss regardless if it is capitalized or not
```

---

And if you need to **differentiate between capital and lowercase** "s"s, try this. 
I will use `"43 LobsterS and 3 CrabS"` for input.

```
input_string = "43 LobsterS and 3 CrabS" # Input line
answer = ""
for letter in input_string:
    if letter == "s":
        answer += "s"
    elif letter == "S":
        answer += "S"

print (answer) # Output

# Returns sSS for "43 LobsterS and 3 CrabS"
```